# ArcGIS 10.3.1 - Cutting 2D sections from 3D Polygons

Tags: 3d-analyst, cross-section, multipatch

I have a bunch of 3D Multipatch features that represent the internal rooms in a large building.  I need to be able to cut 2D sections out for any given elevation, ie make a plan view for any given elevation.  I made a Multipatch cutting plane at one of the desired elevation but looking through the 3D Analyst tools I'm at a loss as what I could do next.  It seems it would be simple, any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, 3D in ArcGIS is rarely simple (imo). The only thing I can add is that you might look into the field of geology for some insight, because they are very interested in 3D and GIS. Generally they are cutting cross-sections perpendicular to the ground surface, but the principles should be the same.

Comment: From what I know, what you asking is not possible at the moment in Scene/Pro. You can try a workaround. Lets say you have a room of 6 meters in height and you need a horizontal cut at 2 m in height and at 4 meters in height. You could try to create 3 shapefiles, extrude each with 2 meters and export them as a 3D feature class. There is also this tool https://crossviewgis.com/ , I tried using it and it worked in my case, maybe you could adapt it to your needs.